# Pandas dataframe avoid looping through columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, performance, loops, apply

I have a df with several columns that looks somewhat like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 3 | 2 |
| 6 | 4 | NaN |
| 2 | 4 | NaN |
| 1 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | NaN |
| ... | ... | ... |

I want to create now a new column which is column 'A' multiplied by a scalar (`df['D'] = df['A']*3`  ) but only for those rows, where there is no NaN. In rows where there is a NaN value, I want to use the same row of column B instead and if there is also an NaN I want to use column C and so on. If all columns have NaN, the value is supposed to be NaN as well.

I could use a for-loop where I go through row by row and check above described if-statements, but that seems very unefficient for a big df. Is there any more efficient method to use here? Maybe using df.apply somehow?

Sorry if this question is very obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["D"] = df.bfill(axis=1)["A"] * 3
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B    C     D
0  NaN  3.0  2.0   9.0
1  6.0  4.0  NaN  18.0
2  2.0  4.0  NaN   6.0
3  1.0  NaN  NaN   3.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

---

Explanation:

You want to multiply non-NaN values in "A" column. So lets first try to fill all NaN values in "A" from values right to it. We use [`bfill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html#pandas.DataFrame.bfill) method (back-fill) on row for the task. Then multiply the "A" column by 3.

Comment: Took me a while to decide to +1 this, because the way that I read the question was multiply column A if it existed, if not then column B (without multiplying by a scalar). After rereading the question, though, I think that I misread it and your answer is correct.

Comment: Wow, this looks exactly like what I need, I am struggling to understand how it works though. Thank you! Edit: Ok, I got it, thanks a lot!